# ANDROID - BroadcastReceiver and ImageView

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-imageview, android-broadcastreceiver

im learning Android, and im triying to make and app that changes the image in the imageView when I rotate the phone, I´ve tried to get the broadcast receiver value, I would like some advice in how to do it, here's the code, sorry if its to much code, but i dont know where i am missing

Main Activity:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BroadcastReceiver miReceptor;
IntentFilter intentFilter;
Intent intent;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    miReceptor = new Receptor();
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED");

}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    miReceptor.onReceive(context, intent);

    registerReceiver(miReceptor,intentFilter);


}

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context="com.example.gaboc.covonesrevenge.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/puerta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.814"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/puerta_cerrada01" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/covone_revenge" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String ROTATION_CHANGED="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)   {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ROTATION_CHANGED)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "COVONE'S REVENGE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gaboc.covonesrevenge">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".Receptor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: just override Activity's onConfigurationChanged, and get new configuration from it. You don't need to use a BroadcastReceiver for that.

Comment: Will there be one image for portrait and another one for landscape? Then you should simply use two different layout files and skip the whole BroadcastReceiver business.